# ssl enabled oci connection - unknown cipher suite 157

Tags: ssl, encryption, jdbc, oracle-call-interface, obiee

I am trying to make an ssl based oci connection to Oracle 11g ssl enabled database using OBIEE BI server and Admin tool. The wallet and all required configurations are in place. However the connection establishment fails and in the sqlnet trace file I get the following error.

(12184) [25-OCT-2015 12:45:21:521] ntzcsgtab: INTERNAL ERROR - unknown cipher suite 157.

(12184) [25-OCT-2015 12:45:21:521] ntzcsgtab: failed with error 543

(12184) [25-OCT-2015 12:45:21:521] ntzcsgtab: exit

(12184) [25-OCT-2015 12:45:21:521] ntzini: Could not initialize Cipher Suite table.

(12184) [25-OCT-2015 12:45:21:521] ntzini: failed with error 543

I am not specifying any particular cipher suite in sqlnet.ora either in client or database, and using the default ones.

Next I tried to create jdbc connection using oci driver (using oracle instant client) and using same wallet, in a simple java client program. I was able to successfully establish the SSL enabled connection.

So it seems like Oracle client inside OBIEE might be missing some feature to handle SSL based connection. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance